# How to show a red heart symbol?

Tags: c#, xaml, unicode, windows-phone

I want to show a red heart in XAML. I used this code:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#x2764;" Foreground="Red" />
```

This returns a black heart.

[image]

Yet in Visual Studio it shows a red heart

[image]

How can I make it show a red heart on my phone?

Comment: It is showing a Red Heart on the Phone, you might have an issue on other parts of the xaml

Comment: It shows a black heart on the phone and a red heart in VS2013

Comment: Hey Arn have you somehow solved the problem lately?

Comment: Not really. I gave up and used a polygon instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a red square image resource (big enough to cover all the heart) to your project and apply it as a foreground brush to the TextBlock, like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#x2764;">
  <TextBlock.Foreground>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="red_square.jpg"/>
  </TextBlock.Foreground>
</TextBlock>
```